# Como fazer um programa que imprime o numero de letras do arquivo?

Tags: python, arquivo, contador

O meu está a imprimir o numero de palavras, mas não sei como faz para imprimir o número de letras:

O meu está assim:

```
filename = open(txtfilename)
for line in filename:
    print(line, end ="")
print("\n")
print("There are",len(txtfilename),"letters in the file.")
filename.close()
```

Comment: Em que variável você está acumulando a soma de caracteres?

Comment: Qual a sua definição de letra. Uma letra é mesmo que um caractere ou letra é um caractere caractere não numérico? O seu conceito de letra é válido apenas para o alfabeto latino e algarismos indo-arábicos ou se estenderia a outros alfabetos e sistemas de numeração?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rodei o seu código e está tudo ok, criei um arquivo chamado: 'texto.txt' e me retornou 9 letras, considerando que a string 'texto.txt' tem 9 caracteres.

Mas se a ideia é contar as letras do conteúdo do arquivo, você pode usar a função split() antes e depois a função len().

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).